# $G$ group, $g \in G$ such that $o(g)=p$ prime then $p| |G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is very similar to Cauchy theorem. I think this must be true, but can't find a way to prove it, nor find a counter example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The order of a subgroup always divides the order of the group (I think that is from Lagrange).  So if the element $g$ has order $p$, then the subgroup generated by $g$ has order $p$.  Therefore $p||G|$

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about Lagrange!

Comment: Also, if I may say so, it is not "very similar to Cauchy theorem" (which is more difficult).

Answer (score 4):

From Lagrange, we have the order of a subgroup always divides the order of the group.  So if the element $g$ has order $p$, then the subgroup generated by $g$ has order $p$.  Therefore $p$ must divide $|G|$.

Comment: Thus, at the risk of stating the obvious, the assumption that $p$ is a *prime* order is unneeded.